# is it possible to clone or export a VM from a hyper-v cloud?

Tags: windows, vmware-esxi, hyper-v, virtual-machines, virtualbox

I would like to know how I can get a clone of a machine that we have in our cloud?

We are running hyper-v and are using microsoft virtual machine manager console as a client to manage our virtual hosts and virtual machines.

I know there are options to migrate and clone the machine, but it seems like it only allows you to do these operations on the cloud.

I need the destination to be my local PC. I just need an ISO so that I can run it using virtualbox or vmware.

**How do I clone a VM from hyper-v on to my local physical pc?**

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use one of V2V available solutions.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793147.aspx